# How to get PasteButton in a circle Shape?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Using the PasteButton with the buttonBorderShape for circle, as shown below how can get
the button to show up as a circle.

I'm using Xcode 15 Beta 7

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/buttonbordershape/circle

[image]

```
PasteButton(payloadType: String.self) { strings in
    guard let first = strings.first else { return }
    print(first)
}
.labelStyle(.iconOnly) // To show icon only or .titleOnly to show  title only
.buttonBorderShape(.circle)
```

Comment: Try using `.capsule` instead of `.circle`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
.labelStyle(.iconOnly)
.clipShape(Circle())
```